# My create role command creates a role with "new role" name only

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

If I write the command `!rang moderator 4af7d4`, my bot sends a message saying *"new role created"* and it creates a role with the name `"new role"` instead of the name `"moderator"` (the first argument after the command).

Here is my current code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) =>{
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}rang`)){
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'))return message.channel.send('nincs jogod ehhez!');
    var args = message.content.split(" ");
    args.shift();

    message.guild.roles.create({
        name: args[0],
        color: args[1]
    })
    .then(role =>{ 
        console.log('Rang elkészítve')
        message.channel.send(`${role.name} létrehozva`)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there a question? Did something go wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is your question.

Comment: sorry for my english, im from hungary. I wanted to create a command which create a role. You can give the role name and color. When i write this command (example: !rang Moderator 4af7d4)   the bot is send a message: New Role created, and he create a role, named: new role. Its not colored, and this name is not Moderator. I don 't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RoleManager#create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) accepts an `options` object that has two optional properties, `data` and `reason`. `data` is a [`RoleData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData) and it has properties like `name`, `color`, `position`, `permissions`, etc.

The problem is that you provided an object with two keys; `name` and `color`, but these should be inside the `data` object like this:

```js
roles.create({
  data: {
    name: args[0],
    color: args[1],
  },
})
```

I've made some changes to your code, so here is your full code with comments:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  // move the first args to a variable named command
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // you only need to check the command now, not the prefix
  if (command === 'rang') {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'))
      return message.channel.send('Nincs jogod ehhez!');

    // send an error message if role name is not provided
    if (!args[0])
      return message.channel.send('Rang nevének megadása kötelező');

    message.guild.roles
      .create({
        data: {
          name: args[0],
          // you can add a random colour if the color is not provided
          color: args[1] || 'RANDOM',
        },
      })
      .then((role) => {
        message.channel.send(`${role} rang létrehozva`);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
});
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: köszi szépen! :D

Comment: Szívesen :) If it answered your question, please click the checkmark (✓) above to accept it. Cheers ;)